# Assign datepicker to each array element

Tags: jquery

I have the following javascript

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.datepicker.setDefaults({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
                inline : true,
            });
            var dateFields = ['non_fed_photo_id_exp_date', 'non_fed_id_exp_date', 'federal_photo_id_exp_date'];
            $.each(dateFields, function(field){
                $('#UserRegistration_user_'+field).datepicker({
                    yearRange: '<?php echo date('Y'); ?>:+30'
                });
            });
            $('#UserRegistration_user_dob').datepicker({
                defaultDate: '-20y',
                yearRange: '-100:-15'
            });
        });
```

The UserRegistration_user_dob element is being properly assigned the datepicker but non of the fields in the array are.

Does anything stand out as to what I'm missing / done wrong?

Comment: try `$.each(dateFields, function(index, field) {` first param is the index number...or simply add a css class like 'dpicker' and use that as the selector...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)'s callback takes two parameters, the index and value. You're only using the index.

Try this instead:

```
$.each(dateFields, function (idx,field) {...
```

Your original code would produce selectors like:

```
#UserRegistration_user_0 
#UserRegistration_user_1 
#UserRegistration_user_2
```

My minor modification would yield:

```
#UserRegistration_user_non_fed_photo_id_exp_date 
#UserRegistration_user_non_fed_id_exp_date 
#UserRegistration_user_federal_photo_id_exp_date
```